# Dartlang selenium or phantomjs?

Tags: dart

Is there any way to make selenium like browser tests in Dart lang? I searched on Google but found no help. I need something like Selenium or Phantomjs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webdriver

Comment: This isn't very usable information. What have you tried, what error message do you get ...

Comment: I haven't used it myself. You may take a look at https://github.com/google/webdriver.dart/tree/master/test. The package seems a bit outdated (last update in November)

Answer (score 0):

Angular.Dart uses [Karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma) with the `karma-dart` plugin. You can [see it in action here](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/tree/master/Chapter_02/test).